# onclick function in jquery not work in firefox

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

function:

```
$("#logon").click(function onAction(x){
```

function:

```
<input type="button" value="LogOn" onclick="<%="javascript:onAction("+i+")"%>" id="logon"></td>
```

please give solution...it is not working in firefox 20.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to register an onclick event using jQuery if you set the onclick attribute on your input button tag.

Just replace

```
$("#logon").click(function onAction(x){ ... });
```

with

```
function onAction(x){ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these method for click event.

```
$("#id").live("click", function(){ alert("Hello!"); });    
$(document).delegate("#id", "click", function(){ alert("Hello!"); });  
$(document).on("click", "#id", function(){ alert("Hello!"); });
```

Comment: The server-side variable `i` needs to be passed to the client, this is not done here.

Answer (score 0):

First, i think the onclick attributes in your HTML input tag is useless. (unless it's different in jsp...)

Second, where is your jquery code?
I advise you, if it's not already done, to put it in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#logon").click(function onAction(x){
  //
}
```

Comment: The onclick attribute on the HTML input is not useless, the variable `i` is passed from the server to the client there.

Comment: So he doesn't need a jquery click event, but a simple javascript function: function onAction(x){...}

Answer (score 0):

The script you wrote is actually used inside the document.ready function .
Either make it just function onAction(){} or remove the onClick attribute from the 
html `<input>` element and enclose your script inside the document.ready like

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#address_copy").click(function() {

    /*your code
    }

    });
```

Hope it works

Comment: Doesn't the `onAction(x)` method get called twice then, because it is registered in the `onclick` attribute of the HTML input tag as well?